# Transition shader

Tags: image, actionscript-3, shader, transition

I have created a transition shader.

This is what is does:

```
On each update the color that should be alpha changes.
Then preform a check for each pixel.
    If the color of the pixel is more that the 'alpha' value
      Set this pixel to transparent.
    Else If the color of the pixel is more that the 'alpha' value - 50
      Set this pixel to partly transparent.
    Else
      Set the color to black.
```

EDIT (DELETED OLD PARTS):

I tried converting my GLSL into AGAL (using http://cmodule.org/glsl2agal):

Fragment shader:

```
const float alpha = 0.8;
varying vec2 TexCoord; //not used but required for converting
uniform sampler2D transition;//not used but required for converting

void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(transition, TexCoord.st);//not used but required for converting

    color.a = float(color.r < alpha);

    if(color.r >= (alpha - 0.1)){
        color.a = 0.2 * (color.r - alpha - 0.1);
    }

    gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, color.a);
}
```

And I've customized the output and added that to a (custom) Starling filter:

```
var fragmentShader:String =
    "tex ft0, v0, fs0 <2d, clamp, linear, mipnone>                  \n" + // copy color to ft0
    "slt ft0.w, ft0.x, fc0.x                                        \n" + // alpha = red < inputAlpha
    "mov ft0.xyz, fc1.xyzz                                          \n" + // set color to black
    "mov oc, ft0";

mShaderProgram = target.registerProgramFromSource(PROGRAM_NAME, vertexShader, fragmentShader);
```

It works and when I set the filters alpha, it will update the stuff. The only thing left is the partly transparent thing, but I have no idea how I can do that.

Comment: I know pretty much zero about starling however I would suggest you use http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html to handle the color transitions. I am pretty sure with that if you build the matrix correctly you can get the same effect at 1000 times the speed over the looping method.

Comment: Yeah, starling has filters too so thats basically the same, although I have no idea how I would achieve this kind of behavior with a color matrix filter.

Answer (score 4):

Swap the cycle on the Y and X coordinates. By using the X in the inner loop you optimize the L1 cache and the prefetcher of the CPU.

Some minor hints:
Remove the zeros for a cleaner code:

```
const c:uint = a << 24
```

Verify that 255/50 is collapsed into a single constant by the compiler.

Comment: Can you provide any details or links that would suggest that this section of code is being stored in L1 cache? And also details on how swapping the loops would force usage in the L1 cache.

Comment: Swapping the loops did help, it is now 23 FPS instead of 20.(I've edited the code in my post)

Although its still not as fast as I would ike it to be. Is this kind of functionality possible in another way ?

I've done this before using GLSL but I know nothing about AGAL.

Comment: It's possible that most of the time is spent inside getPixel and setPixel, did you measure the maximum theoretical speed with: tempBitmapData.setPixel32(x, y, bitmapData.getPixel(x, y)) ?;  P.S. by editing the code my answer may be considered "wrong" now (!)

Answer (score 1):

Don't be crazy by doing it with BitmapData once you're using Starling.

I didn't get if you're grayscaling it by yourself or not. In not, just create a [Starling filter](http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/filters) for grayscale (pixel shader below will do the trick)

```
tex ft0, v0, fs0 <2d,linear,clamp>
add ft1.x, ft0.x, ft0.y
add ft1.x, ft1.x, ft0.z
div ft1.x, ft1.x, fc0.x
mov ft0.xyz, ft1.xxx
mov oc ft0
```

And for the alpha transition just extend the Image Class, implement IAnimatable add it to the Juggler. in the advanceTime just do a `this.alpha -= VALUE`;

Simple like that :)

Comment: Its not as simple as that ;P Lets take this image as an example:

[Battle.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4l7tulsduas242b/Battle.png)

On each update the color that should be alpha changes.
Then preform a check for each pixel.
    If the color of the pixel is more that the 'alpha' value.
      Set this pixel to transparent.
    Else.
      Set the color to black.

Comment: You just need to do a check for the pixel and kill that pixel in the shader. Later on I can post the AGAL shader... right now I don't have time. Ps.: you said that you had done this with GLSL, just convert it to agal and use it; here's a glsl2agal converter http://www.cmodule.org/glsl2agal/ Cheers

Comment: :O GLSL to AGAL :O

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Just going to elaborate a bit on @Paxel's answer. I discussed with another developer Jackson Dunstan about the L1 caching, where the speed improvement comes from, and what other improvements can be made to  code like this to see performance gain.

After which Jackson posted a blog entry which can be read at here: [Take Advantage of CPU caching](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2491)

I'll post some the relative items. First the bitmap data is stored in memory by rows. The rows memory addresses might look something like this:

```
   row 1: 0 1 2 3 4 5
   row 2: 6 7 8 9 10 11
   row 3: 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

Now running your inner loop through the rows will allow you leverage the L1 cache advantage since you can read the memory in order. So inner looping X first you'll read the first row as:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

But if you were to do it Y first you'd read it as:

```
0 6 12 1 7 13
```

As you can see you are bouncing around memory addresses making it a slower process.

As for optimizations that could be made, the suggestion is to cache your width and height getters, storing the properties into local variables. Also using the `Math.round()` is pretty slow, replacing that would see a speed increase.